# Linking transactions to Purchase Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently attempting to create an inventory report using data from inventory transactions. I have an inventory table that resembles the one below, and I'm working on generating a report that identifies which claim transactions are associated with purchase orders. It's important to note that in some cases, a single claim transaction quantity can be split and associated with two different purchase orders due to the nature of our pack size ordering process. I've made an initial query attempt, but I'm struggling to properly split these transactions. The query performed perfectly, but I had to account for specific cases where it didn't work as expected. Some transactions have reversals. For instance, consider the scenario where the C0 claim transaction is executed and then reversed before an order is placed. Hence, it shouldn't be considered in the linking result. However, the C3 claim gets reversed at a later stage, allowing the original C3 transaction to link with the O1 and O2 orders. Yet, the reversed C3 claim should be ignored for linking purposes, and part of C8 should also be disregarded due to the impact of C3 on inventory. I'd really appreciate your help in handling this particular situation. I am adding the insert script and expected result below

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I have put the scripts for sample data and expected result.

```
CREATE TABLE tempInventory (
Date DATE,
Sponsor VARCHAR(255),
Pharmacy VARCHAR(255),
Drug VARCHAR(255),
TransactionType VARCHAR(255),
TransactionValue VARCHAR(255),
Quantity INT,
QuantityOnHand INT
);

INSERT INTO tempInventory (Date, Sponsor, Pharmacy, Drug, TransactionType, TransactionValue, Quantity, QuantityOnHand)

VALUES
('2023-01-01', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C0', -60, -60),
('2023-01-01', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C0', 60, 0), --Reversed
('2023-01-01', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C1', -30, -30),
('2023-01-02', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C2', -60, -90),
('2023-01-03', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C3', -30, -120),
('2023-01-04', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'PurchaseOrder', 'O1', 100, -20),
('2023-01-05', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C4', -30, -50),
('2023-01-06', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C5', -60, -110),
('2023-01-06', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C6', -120, -230),
('2023-01-07', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C7', -30, -260),
('2023-01-08', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'PurchaseOrder', 'O2', 200, -60),
('2023-01-09', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C8', -40, -100),
('2023-01-09', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C3', 30, -70), --Reversed
('2023-01-09', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'Claim', 'C9', -30, -100),
('2023-01-11', 'CO', 'P1', 'D1', 'PurchaseOrder', 'O3', 100, 0);
```

```
TransactionValue1 TransactionValue2 LinkedQuantity
O1 C1 -30
O1 C2 -60
O1 C3 -10
O2 C3 -20
O2 C4 -30
O2 C5 -60
O2 C6 -90
O3 C6 -30
O3 C7 -30
O3 C8 -10
O3 C9 -30
```

Query I am trying

```
WITH RunningTotals AS
(
SELECT i.[Date]
, i.Sponsor
, i.Pharmacy
, i.Drug
, i.TransactionType
, i.TransactionValue
, i.Quantity
, i.QuantityOnHand
, COALESCE(SUM(i.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY i.Sponsor, i.Pharmacy, i.Drug, i.TransactionType ORDER BY i.[Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS PrevRunningTotal
, SUM(i.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY i.Sponsor, i.Pharmacy, i.Drug, i.TransactionType ORDER BY i.[Date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS CurRunningTotal
FROM tempInventory AS i
), Claims AS
(
SELECT rt.Date
, rt.Sponsor
, rt.Pharmacy
, rt.Drug
, rt.TransactionType
, rt.TransactionValue
, rt.Quantity
, rt.QuantityOnHand
, -rt.PrevRunningTotal AS PrevRunningTotal
, -rt.CurRunningTotal AS CurRunningTotal
FROM RunningTotals AS rt
WHERE rt.TransactionType = 'Claim'
), PurchaseOrders AS
(
SELECT rt.Date
, rt.Sponsor
, rt.Pharmacy
, rt.Drug
, rt.TransactionType
, rt.TransactionValue
, rt.Quantity
, rt.QuantityOnHand
, rt.PrevRunningTotal
, rt.CurRunningTotal
FROM RunningTotals AS rt
WHERE rt.TransactionType = 'PurchaseOrder'
)
SELECT po.TransactionValue
, c.TransactionValue
, CASE WHEN c.CurRunningTotal > po.CurRunningTotal
THEN c.PrevRunningTotal - po.CurRunningTotal
WHEN c.PrevRunningTotal < po.PrevRunningTotal
THEN po.PrevRunningTotal - c.CurRunningTotal
ELSE c.Quantity
END AS LinkedQuantity
FROM Claims AS c
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrders AS po
ON c.Sponsor = po.Sponsor
AND c.Pharmacy = po.Pharmacy
AND c.Drug = po.Drug
AND (c.PrevRunningTotal < po.CurRunningTotal and c.TranDate <= po.TranDate)
AND po.PrevRunningTotal < c.CurRunningTotal
```

Comment: Is there such a thing as a partial reversal?

Comment: No, there won't be any partial reversal, it will be exactly same quantity that will get reversed.

Comment: Thinking it through... Without the reversals, I believe it would be a straightforward matter of assigning sequence ranges to claims (1..30, 31..90, 91..120, 121..150, 151..210, etc) and orders (1..100, 101..200, etc), matching them up and generating a "fulfillment" row for any overlap between claims sequence numbers and purchase sequence numbers. The trick is the reversals. If a reversal occurs before fulfilled the fulfilling purchase, we can just deallocate (which may have a ripple effect). In other cases, the purchase fulfils the claim, but the reversal may effectively fulfill another claim.

Comment: ...So, after zeroing out the effects of claims having reversals before being fulfilled, I believe we could treat the reversals as almost the same as purchases. Fulfilled allocations are returned to inventory and might fulfil pending or future claims.  I also can envision a case where a claim is only partially fulfilled before reversal, so the effect is split. Likewise, a reversal might be partially zeroed out (not yet fulfilled), partially contributing to the fulfillment of another pending claim (or claims), and partially contributing to the fulfillment of another future claim (or claims).

Comment: I think this is doable. The reversing calculation (pre-fulfillment vs post-fulfillment) might require iterative logic, but once that is out of the way, the rest might fall into place. Finding a clean way to represent reversing back to inventory will be the key. *Does it sound like I am on the right track?*

Comment: By my thinking, the result should also include a row `C3, C8, -30`, reflecting the fact that the quantity returned to inventory by the C3 reversal was used to partially fulfil C8. Alternately, we could generate an R1 restock transaction and have both `R1 C3 30` and `R1 C8 -30`. That might work better, as the sum totals for each Claim, Purchase, and Restock (always net zero) would be consistent. (I suspect the DEA likes consistency.)

Comment: See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2KHCaYwI) for work in progress. The logic was developed from scratch, but is not too much different from what you had so far. This handles the fulfilment allocations, including the reallocation of a non-canceling reversal. I commented out the canceling reversal "C0" for now (to be delt with later). It might be a day or three before I can look at logic to identify and handle those cases. *Interestingly, the logic reallocated the "C3" reversal to the residual C6 claim instead of C8, since C6 was the oldest as-of-yet unfulfilled claim still pending.*

Comment: Another possibility is a purchase order may more than cover pre-ceding claims and therefore fulfill a later claim either partially or in full

Comment: Absolutely, your analysis is right on point. You've detailed precisely how the reversal and partial split functions should operate. A crucial rule is that a purchase order should exclusively link to claim transactions that occurred before the purchase order's date (ensuring all linked claim transaction dates precede the purchase order date).

Regarding the sequencing, purchase orders cannot stem from future claims for clear reasons.

Comment: Additionally, to streamline the initial phase and manage complexity, I initiated with simpler scenarios. However, there are instances where an inventory adjustment might involve a negative or positive quantity. I'm assuming these will be treated as claims if the quantity is negative and as orders if the quantity is positive. 
I really appreciate you helping on this.

Comment: Also, I'm using SQL Server 2019, which doesn't support the "Greatest" function. Are there any alternatives available for achieving a similar operation?

Comment: The alternative to the `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` is a `CASE` expression or `IIF()` function. Something like `CASE WHEN a < b THEN a ELSE b END` or `IIF(a < b, a, b)` - the latter being a bit more compact.

Comment: Regarding the "purchase never fulfilling a future claim rule", I would have two potential problem scenarios: (1) Someone makes a mistake and orders too many. Is the excess discarded? Might need an adjusting transaction for that. (2) What is a previously-fulfilled claim is reversed and there are insufficient pending claims to consume the reversed inventory. In that case the inventory would go positive and could then fulfil a future claim. Another case for an adjustment of we can't allow that to happen. (I don't know about "clear reasons".)

Comment: Regarding inventory adjustments, I agree. Any additions would be grouped with the purchase orders and subtractions grouped with claims. I think the numbering and matching would all fall into place.

Comment: By the way, you may have noticed in my earlier [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2KHCaYwI) that I added sequence numbers to establish a well-defined ordering. Dates by themselves are not enough, and any indeterminant ordering could produce squirrelly results. I would hope that your live data has some way to identify ordering unambiguously.

Comment: The other big loose end is preprocessing data to identify, flag, and later exclude unfulfilled or part-fulfilled reversed claims. Might need a separate *ReversalAdjustment* column to track this. Similarly, you might need to preprocess the data to identify any positive inventory points and insert zeroing adjustments to prevent future claim fulfulment. My gut feeling is that these may need to be an iterative processes, since the insertion of an adjustment effects all following data and would influence the conditions and amounts of future adjustments. (Out for now. Will check back tomorrow.)

Comment: My bad,I should have provided some context. The purchase order is generated once the Quantity on Hand (QOH) hits a certain threshold in our automated system. Generally, the system doesn't over-order, but there's a slim chance that a manual order might be placed in error on rare occasions.

Regarding linking the purchase order to claims, the priority is to complete linking with all prior claims first using factors such as dates or sequence numbers. Only if there isn't sufficient quantity available, in those exceptional cases, should it draw from future claims.

Comment: Yes, in the live data, I have primary key to help with sorting.
Yes, you are right. Reversal claim links should be flagged, allowing them to serve for reporting purposes. As for the positive inventory, there's no necessity to compel adjustments to zero it out. Since the automated system only initiates orders upon hitting the threshold, instances of positive inventory won't prompt the system to trigger orders assuming the presence of existing inventory that can be utilized by pharmacy.

Comment: With these cases addressed, finalizing the script would be a great help. Once again, I truly appreciate all your assistance.

Comment: I haven't done any more on this, but have given it some thought. I think the answer to the reversal issue is to just to code a loop to: (1) Perform the previously discussed logic. (2) Search the results for any reversed claim where a reversal was recorded earlier than any purchase matched up to fulfill that claim. (3) Update those claims an reversals with an adjustment value in a separate column. (4) Toss the current results and repeat this process until no more adjustments are needed. The logic need updating to include the adjustment. Note that an adjustment might just be a partial. Good luck